# Fast and efficient way to hash long string to values in a given range

Tags: ruby, string, hash

What is the most efficient way to hash random strings (of maximum 1024 characters, they can be UTF8) to integer values from 0 to 100? I think calculating CRC is the fastest but I'm not sure.

EDIT: The only requirement for this hash is to be super fast and not to change between sessions (same data => same hash value)

Comment: What requirements do you have of the hash? Maybe you could just take the sum of character values modulo 101.

Comment: Tim - yap sum of characters values modulo 101 seems the best (kinda like CRC but should be faster).

Comment: are you input "random" strings ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```
"af".sum % 100 # => 99
"ag".sum % 100 # => 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Use any hash function, convert that to an integer value, then calculate the modulus of 100.

Example using MD5:

```
require 'digest/md5'

def hash_100(str)
  Digest::MD5.hexdigest(str).to_i(16) % 100
end

hash_100('hello') # => 94
hash_100('world') # => 51
```

I suspect there's a way to get the integer straight from the Digest without going through a hex first, but this was on top of my head.

Comment: MD5 digest is definitely not the fastest way.

Comment: "Use any hash function" - I never suggested it was.